# asp.net changepassword control

Tags: asp.net, controls, change-password

How to work with asp.net changepassword control. When I click the change password button it always gives an error:

```
Invalid password or new password is invalid. The minimum length of new password 7. You want to use non-alphanumeric characters: 1.
```

I type new password like "Changepassword123", but the error is still occuring.

The codebehind code is:

```
protected void changep1_ChangedPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(changep1.CurrentPassword);
            Response.Write(changep1.NewPassword);

        }
```

Can someone provide the codebehind code to update user password?
Thanks!

Comment: see this http://forums.asp.net/t/1160030.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error says you need at least 1 non alphanumeric character in your new password. You can change this.

In web.config you can update the minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters setting.

```
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
```

See membership provider setting below that set the minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters attribute to 0

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
      connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
      enablePasswordReset="true" 
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
      minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
      passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
      applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```